# Ansible: most elegant way to download Azure blob to Windows VM?

Tags: windows, ansible, azure-blob-storage

I'm looking for the most elegant way to download a blob hosted in an Azure storage account to a Windows VM using Ansible.

So, from the reading and experimenting I've been doing, my understanding is that it's difficult/impossible to run any Ansible modules other than the win_ prefixed modules on Windows VMs, but it's possible to use other modules if you delegate to localhost, for e.g.:

```
- name: Retrieve my Blob
  azure_rm_storageblob:
    resource_group: myresourcegroup
    storage_account_name: mystorageacct
    container: mystoragectnr
    blob: idunnosomeinstaller.zip
    dest: '/app/install/idunnosomeinstaller.zip'
  delegate_to: localhost
```

While this might be fine for most azure_rm_ modules, the result here is that the blob is downloading to the Ansible host and not the Windows VM being configured, so I'm faced with adding a

```
- name: Copy my Installer
  win_copy:
    src: '/app/install/idunnosomeinstaller.zip'
    dest: "C:\\Build\\idunnosomeinstaller.zip"
```

task after the blob retrieval to localhost, and it seems pretty inelegant and time-consuming to download *and then* copy?

The other option I'm considering is installing the Azure CLI on the remote host and executing a PowerShell script remotely to pull the blob, but I'd rather the host being configured not authenticate to Azure if I can help it.

Are there any tricks or doc I'm missing that would make this easier? How would you do it? :)

Comment: did you find the answer then, how did you have accomplish this?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same with windows server but I keep having connection refused with localhost.

Answer (score 0):

well, to download a blob from a private storage account you'd need to auth. if you don't want the target vm to auth to azure your only option is to auth in ansible and download it to the host and push it to the vm.

you don't have to use Azure Cli, you can use Azure Powershell on the vm, but the auth problem still stands.