# ansible module azure.azcollection keeps failing on windows target

Tags: windows, azure, ansible

I want to use azure.azcollection to download the blob from Azure storage account. This is in my playbook. The examples from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/key-vault-configure-secrets?tabs=ansible uses localhost

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Download the file
      azure.azcollection.azure_rm_storageblob:
        resource_group: 'myRG'
        storage_account_name: 'mySA'
        container: mycontainer
        blob: 'folder/file.txt'
        dest: 'C:\Temp\folder\file.txt'
      delegate_to: localhost
```

and localhost connects through winrm and the connection is refused.

```
   azure-arm.azure_image:     "changed": false,
   azure-arm.azure_image:     "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f42dc0618e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))",
   azure-arm.azure_image:     "unreachable": true
   azure-arm.azure_image: }
```

I have been looking for the solution but I could not find examples working on windows VM. I know this can be done with powershell but I am required to use ansible.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f42dc0618e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))",
```

I received the same error while connecting to Windows VM from ansible host, Refer below:-

[image]

In order to resolve this error create a new yml file with the code below. I took inspiration from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799498/ansible-most-elegant-way-to-download-azure-blob-to-windows-vm) by **Nathan C** and answer by **4c74356b41** with this [official Ansible Azure blob document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_storageblob_module.html).

> ```yaml
> - hosts: all
>
> vars_prompt:
>
> - name: ansible_password
>
> prompt: "Enter local administrator password"
>
> vars:
>
> ansible_user: siliconuser
>
> ansible_connection: winrm
>
> ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
>
> ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
>
> tasks:
>
> - name: Test connection
>
> win_ping:
> ```

Run the below commands in your ansible host to connect to Windows VM. I have referred the below command from this [official ansible document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html)

```bash
ansible-playbook connect_windows_vm.yml -i 20.49.178.48, ...
```

Output:-
Got connected to the VM successfully like below:-

[image]

Make sure the winrm in your target VM is enabled and firewall restrictions are removed. Also, Add Inbound NSG rule to allow Port 5986 in Azure VM like below:-

I have referred the below [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic#create-security-rules) to open ports in NSG:-

> [image]
>
> **And also check your Vm’s Firewall settings by following this [link](https://help.mashme.io/support/solutions/articles/29000036898-how-to-see-if-windows-firewall-is-blocking-a-port-or-program)
> like below to allow inbound connection to winrm service:-**
>
> [image]

I tried connecting to my Windows VM and download the Blob but received an error, As Ansible modules have certain limitations while running for Windows host.

***As an alternative instead of using Powershell, you can make use of azcopy command from this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download) link to download the file from blob storage to local Windows VM like below:-***

> **az copy command:-**
>
> ```bash
> azcopy copy "https://siliconstrg56.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=xxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdlacupiytfx&se=2023-04-12T17:30:12Z&st=2023-04-12T09:30:12Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAVdROvKFEd%2F58mE%3D" "C:\folder" --recursive=true
> ```
>
> **Output:-**
>
> [image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

**Local:-**

[image]